# What does "App" button in Home-Switch do?

Tags: macos, accessibility

Sys Prefs / Accessibility / Switch Control / check Enable Switch Control

Home-Switch (depicted) window pops up with a button labeled "Application."

It's supposed to "controls the application in use. This scans through individual items or groups in the active window."  But I don't see it!  Nothing happens when I click on it.  Does it do anything for you?[image]